# A lot of high power microscopes have 2500x magnification, why that specific number?

Tags: microscopy

I've been shopping around for a microscope, and I've noticed something I didn't really expect. Across different brands, across different times (look at some "vintage stuff"), many many microscopes have the same advertised magnifications. Is there a physical reason for this? E.g. is 2500x getting nearer to the diffraction limit or something? Perhaps it has something to do with the physics of lenses?